# I am pleased with your answer. Is "pleased" a verb or an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, semantics, past-participles, active-voice

> **Your  answer  pleases  me**(Active  voice)
>
> **I am pleased  with  your  answer.**(passive voice)

I  think it  is  difficult  to  say  whether **pleased**  is  a  participle   or  an  adjective in the sentence in the  passive 
voice We  know  that  pleased  can  be  a  verb  and  an  adjective  too.

If  somebody  asked  us  to  say  whether  pleased  is  an adjective or  a verb  in the  sentence, what  would  be  our  answer.?

En

I  think  we  will face the  problem when  verbs
such  as  satisfy, please , interest  which   can be adjectives as  past  participles  are  used  as  verbs.

> **English  interests  me.**( active  voice)
>
> **I am  interested  in English**(passive voice)

Here intersted  is  both  a verb  and adjective.

The  problem  arises  when  past  participles  and adjective forms are  the  same.

> **He   likes me**(active voice)
>
> **I am liked by him**(  passive voice)

Here  liked  is clearly   a  verb

Here  is  a links  which  show pleased  as  an adjective. and  please  as  a verb.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pleased

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/please_2

This  is  not  at all  a  dupiicate  because   **staple**  is  a  verb  and  stapled  is  the  past  participle  of  staple  but it  is  not  adjective but  pleased , satisfied, and  dissatisfied   are  listed as  verbs  and  adjectives.

Even if  we  change  the  tense  they  are  difficult  to  classify.

> **I was  pleased with  your  answer.**
>
> **I  was  satisfied with  your  answer**

**I  will  be  satisfied with  your answer**

**I  will  be  pleased  with  your  answer**

Here  is  a  link  which  shows    **staple**   only  as  a  verb

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stapled

Here  is  another  link   which  shows     **satisfy** as  a verb   followed  by  the  preposition   with

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satisfy

Comment: Incorrect presupposition: _I am pleased with your answer_ is not Passive. Passive would use _by_, and it would more likely be past tense, reporting a completed event of the answer pleasing the speaker, and not a current state of the speaker's _being pleased with_ it (which is a predicate adjective).

Comment: Some examples are easier to parse than others. _Jack was married, but Joe was single._ /  _John was married to Jill* on the fifth of November._ [*and vice-versa for those looking for possible examples of sexism]

Comment: I  think  I  have  shown  many  links  and  examples  to  show  that  satisfy, please  etc  are  difficult  to  classify  in  the  passive.The  previous  questions  were  not  as detailed

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100477/discussion-between-justin-and-englishmonger).

Comment: @ Bill J.Thank  you  I hope  this  question  is   kept  open as  it  is  really  a genuine  question.

Comment: Yes, "pleased" is an adjective as evident from the fact that it can be modified by "very". Same applies to "satisfied".